# naming plots using ggplot, that are being looped by lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a list of plots (by `ggplot2`) using `lapply`

let's say I have this function

```
plot <- function(x){
  ggplot(x,aes(x=timepoints,means)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_line() +
       scale_x_continuous(name='some name') +
       scale_y_continuous(name='another name') +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-stderrs,ymax=means+stderrs),width=2) + 
       opts(title = names(x))    
}
```

I'm going to loop this through a list of data frames, here is an example of two data frames within the list:

```
$name1

   means    stderrs        timepoints
1  603.784863 289.952382       0
2  120.00     99.000           20
$name2
   means   stderrs
1  17.425819  5.204339         0
2  25.9       8.0              20
```

My problem:
  the `names(x)` part of my ggplot function will name each plot 'means' as opposed to the actual name of that data frame (e.g. name1,name2)
the function is in `list[[i]]` and I want the the name of that actual data frame, which would be `names(list[i])`.

question:
   is there a way to refer to an outer layer in the list, so to speak? or is there an easier way to get a list of these plots w/ their respective names?

Comment: Rarely do you need to use this construct in `ggplot`.  Can you expand your question with a complete example including the initial list that you're subsetting?

Comment: that looks like you're going to plot a single point that has an undefined `x` coordinate, `timepoints`.  You can always add another item to your lists that holds the name.  But shortest answer is no, `lapply` only looks at the data inside the elements of a list and has no knowledge of the outer list or its names. Or use `lapply(seq_along(yourlist), ...)` and index similarly to the way you described.

Comment: It's doable. It requires some changes in your code thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works.

```
plot2 <- function(x, title){
  ggplot(x,aes(x=timepoints,means)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_line() +
      scale_x_continuous(name='some name') +
      scale_y_continuous(name='another name') +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-stderrs,ymax=means+stderrs),width=2) + 
      opts(title = title)
}

lapply(names(your_list), function(x) plot2(your_list[[x]], x))
```